# Bootstrap 4 Modal alignment issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

The Bootstrap Modal has suddenly decided to fail on me.. Been searching for a solution but nothing matches my issue since I'm not using Bootbox or a beta version.

Here's what the modal looks like:
[image]

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="successmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="successmodalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="successmodalLabel">This is a title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is a message
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I show it using jquery and I'm using this CDN:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

this style CDN(?):

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to many reasons:

Any css overrides of modal or title or close button
Its can be easily solved by

```
<h4 class="modal-title pull-left" id="successmodalLabel">This is a title</h4>
```

If no 
then

```
#successmodalLabel{
display:inline;
float:left;
}
```

or use

```
 #successmodalLabel{
    display:inline;
     width:100%;
     text-align:left;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, last solution somewhat worked, this was the result: https://gyazo.com/79e2f3e89a6659eb4d228ed1f1158b7b

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue !
Somehow it was corrected just by interchnging the button and title positions i.e.

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id="successmodalLabel">This is a title</h4>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you add all your content properly?

I am able to get the bootstrap modal perfectly. Check the codepen here: https://codepen.io/immnk/pen/dmKPow[Codepen](https://codepen.io/immnk/pen/dmKPow)

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember to have these included:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your title is on the right is because bootstrap adds:

```
.modal-header .close{
    margin: -1rem -1rem -1rem auto;
}
```

Forcing the close button to the right and in your case the title as it is after the button